# C# Rijndael CryptographicException "Length of the data to encrypt is invalid."

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndael

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a file with the rijndael algorythm, but i have been getting the error "Length of the data to encrypt is invalid.". I am able to encrypt the file, but i can't decrypt it. This is my decryption function;

```
    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] toEncryptArray)
    {
        byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("-key-");
        RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
        rDel.Key = keyArray;
        rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateDecryptor();
        return cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
    }
```

I honestly have no idea what i am doing wrong, as i can encrypt it perfectly fine. The file i am trying to decrypt is 11 kb.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exception you're getting? You should get one when you try to set the key since it's an invalid length.

Comment: @Lee Yes i am sure thats the exception i'm getting, that is not my real key. The real key is way longer, and i have tested it out with another key and then it comes up with an error that is in fact related to the key.

Comment: Please add Your Encryption code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Length of the data to decrypt is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942139/length-of-the-data-to-decrypt-is-invalid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx) object, which will automatically call the correct `ICryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock` and `ICryptoTransform.TransformBlock` methods.

You haven't posted the encryption code but check that the *Padding* mode the same (i.e. `PaddingMode.PKCS7`) and the initiation vector is set to the same string.