# CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption

I get "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid" when I try to decrypt my file.

```
public class EncryptDecrypt
    {
        //  Call this function to remove the key from memory after use for security
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "RtlZeroMemory")]
        public static extern bool ZeroMemory(IntPtr Destination, int Length);

        // Function to Generate a 64 bits Key.
        public static string GenerateKey()
        {
            // Create an instance of Symetric Algorithm. Key and IV is generated automatically.
            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCrypto = (DESCryptoServiceProvider)DESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();

            // Use the Automatically generated key for Encryption. 
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
        }

        public static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename,
           string sOutputFilename,
           string sKey)
        {
            FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(sInputFilename,
               FileMode.Open,
               FileAccess.Read);

            FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename,
               FileMode.Create,
               FileAccess.Write);
            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
            ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
            CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted,
               desencrypt,
               CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
            fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            cryptostream.Close();
            fsInput.Close();
            fsEncrypted.Close();
        }

        public static void DecryptFile(string sInputFilename,
           string sOutputFilename,
           string sKey)
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            //A 64 bit key and IV is required for this provider.
            //Set secret key For DES algorithm.
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
            //Set initialization vector.
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

            //Create a file stream to read the encrypted file back.
            FileStream fsread = new FileStream(sInputFilename,
               FileMode.Open,
               FileAccess.Read);
            //Create a DES decryptor from the DES instance.
            ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
            //Create crypto stream set to read and do a 
            //DES decryption transform on incoming bytes.
            CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread,
               desdecrypt,
               CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            //Print the contents of the decrypted file.
            StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFilename);
            fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
            fsDecrypted.Flush();
            fsDecrypted.Close();
        }
    }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Must be 64 bits, 8 bytes.
            // Distribute this key to the user who will decrypt this file.
            string sSecretKey;
            //ExportCSV.EncryptDecrypt c = new EncryptDecrypt();
            // Get the Key for the file to Encrypt.
            sSecretKey = EncryptDecrypt.GenerateKey();

            // For additional security Pin the key.
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(sSecretKey, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            // Encrypt the file.        
            EncryptDecrypt.EncryptFile(@"C:\Test\Sample.xml",
               @"C:\Test\Encrypted.xml",
               sSecretKey);

            // Decrypt the file.
            EncryptDecrypt.DecryptFile(@"C:\Test\Sample.xml",
               @"C:\Test\Decrypted.xml",
               sSecretKey);

            // Remove the Key from memory. 
            EncryptDecrypt.ZeroMemory(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), sSecretKey.Length * 2);
            gch.Free();
        }
```

I get the error while trying to write the decrypted data to file
fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Length of the data to decrypt is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942139/length-of-the-data-to-decrypt-is-invalid)

Comment: Usually, when working with cryptography, we put data into 'blocks' of a certain size. The size of each block will depend on the various parameters/options used. Your problem could also be that you just need to pad out the end of a line to a certain number of bits. Either way, please see the linked question for more help. If that doesn't help, try the [Length of the data to decrypt is invalid](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/109523/Length-of-the-data-to-decrypt-is-invalid) page on CodeProject.